# What is the use of allowBlank: false in extjs fields

Tags: javascript, extjs

I have a textfield in a Panel. For example:

```
{
    xtype:'textfield',
    id:'usap8',
    width:199,
    height:26,
    colspan:1,
    margin: '1 0 1 0',
    allowBlank: false,
    fieldStyle: 'text-align: center;'
}
```

Will I be able to restrict the panel submission? If not, what is the use of `allowBlank` config?

Answer (score 3):

`allowBlank` does not automatically restrict form submission.

Instead, it is a config that is for instance relevant if you ask whether the form is valid:

```
if(form.isValid()) form.submit()
```

In the [`isValid`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/source/Basic.html#Ext-form-Basic-method-isValid) function, all fields are asked whether they are valid:

```
invalid = me.getFields().filterBy(function(field) {
        return !field.validate();
    });
```

`field.validate()` calls `field.isValid()`, which calls `field.getErrors()`.

The `Ext.form.field.Text` has the following line in its function [`getErrors`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/source/Text2.html#Ext-form-field-Text-method-getErrors):

```
if (trimmed.length < 1 || (value === me.emptyText && me.valueContainsPlaceholder)) {
    if (!me.allowBlank) {
        errors.push(me.blankText);
    }
```

and HERE the config you have said has the effect that an error is thrown if the field is blank.

That error then ripples back through aforementioned functions until `form.isValid()` returns `false` (but you could also find out about the error if you call `field.validate()`, `field.isValid()` or `field.getErrors()` manually)...

Comment: +1, Thank you for the elaborate answer. I have right now written manual validations for checking empty fields. I will use the above code that you have given and get back here.

Answer (score 1):

For restricting form panel text value submission, use

```
submitvalue: false
```

Refer: http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/5.0/apidocs/#!/api/Ext.form.field.File-cfg-submitValue

While, 
 allowBlank:false will restrict the form submission if the field is blank.

Answer (score 0):

`allowBlank` simply tells the Validator that your field may or may not be empty upon validation/submission.
If you do validation of panel/form then `allowBlank:false` should make sure you can't proceed with a blank/empty field there.

Comment: I am unable to understand. Can you please elaborate your answer?